# Modal works, until duplicated

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript modal that I created, which works fine, unless there are 2 on the page. When 2 of them exist on the page, the first one will work, but the next ones do now.

Here is the JS that controls it:

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("js-modal")[0];
trigger.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// Get the modal linked with with trigger element
let modal = document.getElementById(
  trigger.href.substring(trigger.href.indexOf("#") + 1)
);

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
let allClose = modal.getElementsByClassName("js-modal-close");


// All elments linked to the modal can close the modal
for (let i = 0; i < allClose.length; i++) {
  allClose[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

and here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xdex7oe4/). I've tried messing around with using `var` instead of `let`, but not 100% sure on how to scope them to their specific html structures programtically.

Comment: The variable `modal` only refers to one of the modals, and your click handlers are all set up to operate on that one modal.

Comment: Should I be wrapping my `let trigger` in a for loop? or would the whole thing need looped?

Comment: I don't think that will help your click handlers.  However the window.onclick one, you might make it generic by comparing the class of e.target  to 'js-modal'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use unique IDs for each modal:

```
<div id="modal-1" class="m-modal">...</div>
<div id="modal-2" class="m-modal">...</div>
```

and set up the trigger for each one, instead of just the first one:

```
let triggers = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('js-modal'))

triggers.forEach(function(trigger) {
 // ...
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eoy2erpp/1/**

Comment: Well that's embarrassing.. I created my divs dynamically off a template and I guess they all got the modal-1 id. smh. (will accept answer in 3mins)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, dirty but works
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7n0thpjk/)

```
var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("js-modal")[1];
trigger.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("js-modal")[0];
```

You are only binding to the first button in your js. Nothing is bound to your second

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript:

```
    // Get the button that opens the modal
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("js-modal")[0];

let trigger1 = document.getElementsByClassName("js-modal")[1];

trigger.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

trigger1.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// Get the modal linked with with trigger element
let modal = document.getElementById(
  trigger.href.substring(trigger.href.indexOf("#") + 1)
);

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
let allClose = modal.getElementsByClassName("js-modal-close");


// All elments linked to the modal can close the modal
for (let i = 0; i < allClose.length; i++) {
  allClose[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```